# Android video transparency doesn't work, black background displayed

Tags: java, android, video, webm

In the Android Application I'm working on I'm trying to play a **WebM** or a **MP4** video with **transparency** using **VideoView** or **TextureView** but I get a **black background** and I couldn't find a way to remove that background. The video is supposed to replace about 200 png files that were animated (the PNGs take about 50MB and we're trying to replace them with a 0.2MB video).
So far I've tested both MP4 and WebM videos and I keep getting the same black background. I haven't worked with this kind of video before. Any thoughts?
A solution in Java would be much appreciated, but I even Kotlin will do.

P.S: Any solution for displaying videos with alpha channel or chroma key? iOS handles these things better apparently

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2509#issuecomment-286516056

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

thats how `SurfaceView` (`VideoView` extends it) works - this `View` is kind-of cutting a hole in your framework layout and will render some graphics (e.g. video frames) on way faster low/native level without knowledge what is placed under these `View`s in XML layout. thus setting alpha to it is no-op as in fact there is nothing under `VideoView` (so only black background by default). try to use `TextureView`, which is a "newer version" of `SurfaceView`, this should handle `alpha` XML attribute

afaik there is no possibility to use `VideoView`/`SurfaceView` with some transparency nor even change default background color - you have to write own "rendering engine" which would draw your frames on some custom widget extending common `View`, but I aware you that doing this on application level will be very hard and heavy for device (performance will suffer). look for a way for rendering your frames on `TextureView`

PS. read [DOC](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/arch-tv#surface_or_texture) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590852/android-textureview-vs-videoview-performance) SO topic for more details how these `View`s works (and why)

Comment: I've tried with TextureView as well but it just doesn't handle the transparency, it shows the black background